# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, oracle11g

When running the code generated by EntityFramework's scaffolding, i ran into this error:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00904:
> "p0"."ModifiedByNavigationUuid": invalid identifier

Yes, the EntityFramework seems to be concatenating the "navigation" property and the id of the associating object together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this is caused by EntityFramework's inability to distinguish the name of the property and the name of the class.

**Example:**
I have a class named ProductLine and I also have a class named Product.  Product holds a "reference" to ProductLine as Guid.  This will trigger the Oracle error.

```
private Guid ProductLine;
```

**Solution:**
Rename the referencing property.

```
private Guid ProduceLineId;
```